# UITableView Removing empty section after -tableView:moveRowAtIndexPath:ToIndexPath: causes crash

Tags: iphone, objective-c, uitableview

I'm using the `- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView moveRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)fromIndexPath toIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)toIndexPath;`

function, and I detect if the `fromIndexPath` section is empty. If it is, then i have the following code:

```
    NSString *fromSection = [sections objectAtIndex:fromIndexPath.section];
    [savedTable beginUpdates];
    NSIndexSet *indexSections = [NSIndexSet indexSetWithIndex:[sections indexOfObject:fromSection]];
    [savedTable deleteSections:indexSections withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationFade];
    [sections removeObject:fromSection];
    [savedTable endUpdates];
```

But this causes the app to crash with the following error:

*** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: 'Invalid update: invalid number of rows in section 0.  The number of rows contained in an existing section after the update (0) must be equal to the number of rows contained in that section before the update (4), plus or minus the number of rows inserted or deleted from that section (0 inserted, 0 deleted) and plus or minus the number of rows moved into or out of that section (0 moved in, 0 moved out).'

From what the error says, it looks like when I remove the (first) section, it doesnt register so it thinks the 4 rows from the second section have moved to the first section improperly. How would I let it know that the section has been removed and thats why 4 rows have been moved to the first section. That would stop the NSInternalInconsistencyException error.

**Edit: App only crashes if there is a section below the section being removed. Which is why more rows are added "improperly". In that case, when I relaunch the app, the section was successfully removed. All seems normal.

*I have resolved the issue. First of all, I didnt fully update the database when i ended the updates. But even then it wouldnt work. So I just used a delay of 0.1 seconds to delete the section by using -performSelector:withObject:afterDelay: and it worked!

Comment: While moving cells, you sure the `fromIndexPath` section is empty?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This usually happens when the implementation of

```
- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
```

still returns the number of rows in the deleted section for the section index you are about to delete. Please check and make sure that this call will return the number of rows of the "next" section (that'll now take place at the index of the deleted section...).

Answer (score 0):

check if the methods `numberOfRowsInSection` and `numberOfSectionsInTableView` are correct and call `[tableview reloadData]`